# How to check file type of properties file

Tags: java

The program I have is checking for most of the file types, how ever I have a .properties file when run with program it says text/plain rather than properties file. How do I customize my program to figure of mime type(based on extension and content) of properties file:

Code below:

```
public class TikaFileTypeDetector {

    private final Tika tika = new Tika();

    public TikaFileTypeDetector() {
        super();
    }

    public String probeContentType(Path path) throws IOException {
        // Check contents first
        String fileContentDetect = tika.detect(path.toFile());
        if (!fileContentDetect.equals(MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM)) {
            return fileContentDetect;
        }

        // Try file name only if content search was not successful
        String fileNameDetect = tika.detect(path.toString());
        if (!fileNameDetect.equals(MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM)) {
            return fileNameDetect;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Tika tika = new Tika();

        if (args.length != 1) {
            printUsage();
            return;
        }

        Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);

        TikaFileTypeDetector detector = new TikaFileTypeDetector();

        String contentType = detector.probeContentType(path);

        System.out.println("File is of type - " + contentType);
    }

    public static void printUsage() {
        System.out.print("Usage: java -classpath ... "
                + TikaFileTypeDetector.class.getName()
                + " ");
    }
}
```

Following is custom xml for mime-type:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mime-info>
   <mime-type type="application/hello">
          <glob pattern="*.properties"/>
   </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

In the [apache docs](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/parser_guide.html#Add_your_MIME-Type), it says to add a new mime type in xml as above and to add it to the code base. How do I add this to my code now? I couldn't find much info on this

Note: I am using apache tika

Comment: `text/plain` is a reasonable value for java properties files.

Comment: well just add a check that if the mime type is text/plain and the file name ends in .properties, then return your custom mime type value.

Comment: That said, the tika docs indicate that there is a file you can add mimetypes to, based on filename glob patterns:  https://tika.apache.org/1.8/parser_guide.html#Add_your_MIME-Type

Comment: @JPMoresmau Thanks for pointing that out. Any example or link if you have?

Comment: @Gus Thanks for the link. I have created a custom mime type in xml but how do I add this to my program so my app can read new file type. Not much info on the site

Comment: Once you've added the mimetype, you should just be able to use `tika.detect()`  That method takes a string filename, `File`, or `URL`, so you might have to massage your `path` first

Comment: @Gus My class is already using tika.detect(). Do I have to modify this ` if (!fileContentDetect.equals(MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM)) `?

Answer (score 0):

Tika 1.10 or later versions addresses this issue by adding a new mime-type named `text/x-java-properties` to its `tika-mimetypes.xml`

Use the following dependency so that you don't have to get your hands dirty by adding a custom `mimetype.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I would also like to add that, As per the [documentation](https://tika.apache.org/1.10/parser_guide.html#Add_your_MIME-Type), the project team welcomes patches to add any standard mime type If it is missing from `org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml`.

[image: Snapshot from tika api documentation]